# CPTScatterPlot Custom Xaxis label overlaps

Tags: core-plot

I have created a CPTScatterPlot, with custom Xaxislabels defined.

```
var axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet) graph.AxisSet;

// Label x with a fixed interval policy
var x = axisSet.XAxis;
x.LabelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicy.None;
x.MinorTicksPerInterval = 4;
x.PreferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 8;
x.MajorGridLineStyle = major;
x.MinorGridLineStyle = minor;
x.Title = "X Axis";
x.TitleOffset = -30;
x.LabelOffset = 15.0f;


NSMutableArray customLabels = new NSMutableArray (dataToPlot.Count);
foreach (PointF pt in dataToPlot) {
    string xlabel = pt.X.ToString ().PadLeft (6, '0');
    CPTTextStyle tstyle = new CPTTextStyle ();
    tstyle.Color = CPTColor.WhiteColor;
    tstyle.FontSize = 15;


    CPTAxisLabel newLabel = new CPTAxisLabel (xlabel, tstyle);
    newLabel.TickLocation = NSDecimalNumber.FromUInt32(uint.Parse(pt.X.ToString())).NSDecimalValue;
    newLabel.Offset = 3.0f;
    newLabel.Rotation = (float)Math.PI/2f;

    customLabels.Add (newLabel);
}
x.AxisLabels = new NSSet(customLabels);
```

This code works fine, but all the axis labels are overlapped. How to remove the overlapping and display only specific labels in the visible range?

Also how to reload the xaxis when user zooms in or zooms out.
Kindly help, I am struck with this.

Thanks
srrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic label overlap-removal built into Core Plot right now. You'll need to do it yourself based on the size and number of labels. Use a plot space delegate to monitor changes in the plot space and update the tick locations and labels as needed when the plot range changes.